# How to order validation checks correctly

Tags: jquery

Just having a slight issue with my validation. What I want to happen is that I want to check that all rows are added first by showing the validation message at the bottom stating I got so many questions remaining. It is only when all questions have been added and that validation has been passed that it then displays the validation for each individual question such as please select at least one answer or you have selected less answers than the required amount.

At the moment it is doing it the other way round as for example it states I need to select at least one answer and then when this is sorted, then it states that I need to add rest of questions.

```
function validation() {

    var marks = parseInt($("#total-weight").text());
    var _qid = "";
    var _msg = "";

    var maxQuestions = <? php echo(int) $_SESSION['textQuestion']; ?> ;
    var questionsAdded = $('tr.optionAndAnswer').length;

    var alertValidation = "";
    // Note, this is just so it's declared...
    $("tr.optionAndAnswer").each(function () {

        _qid = $("td.qid", this).text();
        _msg = "You have errors on Question Number: " + _qid + "\n";

        $(".numberAnswerTxtRow", this).each(function () {
            var currenttotal = $(this).closest('.optionAndAnswer').find('.answerBtnsOn').length;

            if ($(this).val() == 0) {
                alertValidation += "\n\u2022 You have not selected an answer, please select at least one answer\n";
            } else if (currenttotal < $(this).val()) {
                alertValidation += "\n\u2022 You have selected less answers than the required amount\n";
            }

            if (alertValidation != "") {
                return false; //Stop the each loop 
            }
        });

    });



    if (alertValidation == "") {
        if (questionsAdded < maxQuestions) {
            _msg = '';
            alertValidation = ("You Have Not Added in All of Your Questions \n\n\u2022 You have " + (maxQuestions - questionsAdded) + " Questions Remaining:");
        }
    }

    if (alertValidation != "") {
        alert(_msg + alertValidation);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**BELOW IS THE WHOLE CODE** - In code below it does not display the other validation messages until the number of questions remaining validation has been passed first. The only issue like I mentioned is the validation within the `$(".numberAnswerTxtRow",this).each(function() {` which is also the only function out of the other functions that contains an else if:

```
function validation() {

    var marks = parseInt($("#total-weight").text());
    var _qid = "";
    var _msg = "";

    var maxQuestions = <? php echo(int) $_SESSION['textQuestion']; ?> ;
    var questionsAdded = $('tr.optionAndAnswer').length;

    var alertValidation = "";
    // Note, this is just so it's declared...
    $("tr.optionAndAnswer").each(function () {


        _qid = $("td.qid", this).text();
        _msg = "You have errors on Question Number: " + _qid + "\n";

        $(".textAreaQuestion", this).each(function () {



            if (!this.value || this.value.length < 5) {
                alertValidation += "\n\u2022 You have not entered a valid Question\n";
            }

            if (alertValidation != "") {
                return false; //Stop the each loop 
            }
        });

        $(".numberAnswerTxtRow", this).each(function () {


            var currenttotal = $(this).closest('.optionAndAnswer').find('.answerBtnsOn').length;

            if ($(this).val() == 0) {
                alertValidation += "\n\u2022 You have not selected an answer, please select at least one answer\n";
            } else if (currenttotal < $(this).val()) {
                alertValidation += "\n\u2022 You have selected less answers than the required amount\n";
            }

            if (alertValidation != "") {
                return false; //Stop the each loop 
            }

        });

        $(".txtWeightRow", this).each(function () {


            if (!this.value) {
                alertValidation += "\n\u2022 Please enter in a figure for Number of Marks for this Question\n";
            }

            if (alertValidation != "") {
                return false; //Stop the each loop 
            }
        });


        if (alertValidation != "") {
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (alertValidation == "") {

        if (questionsAdded < maxQuestions) {
            _msg = '';
            alertValidation = ("You Have Not Added in All of Your Questions \n\n\u2022 You have " + (maxQuestions - questionsAdded) + " Questions Remaining:");
        }



    }

    if (alertValidation != "") {
        alert(_msg + alertValidation);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get your problem right this is what you would have to do:

```
$questions = array();

while ($selectedstudentanswerstmt->fetch()) {

    //Check if the student data exist.
    if (!isset($questions[$detailsStudentId])) {
        $questions[$detailsStudentId] = array(
            'studentalias' => $detailsStudentAlias,
            'studentforename' => $detailsStudentForename,
            'studentsurname' => $detailsStudentSurname,
            'questions' => array();
        );
    }

    $questions[$detailsStudentId]['questions'][$detailsQuestionId] = array(
        'questionno'=>$detailsQuestionNo,
        'content'=>$detailsQuestionContent,
        'optiontype'=>$detailsOptionType,
        'noofanswers'=>$detailsNoofAnswers,
        'answer'=>$detailsAnswer,
        'replytype'=>$detailsReplyType,
        'questionmarks'=>$detailsQuestionMarks,
        'studentanswer'=>$detailsStudentAnswer,
        'responsetime'=>$detailsResponseTime,
        'mouseclick'=>$detailsMouseClick,
        'studentmark'=>$detailsStudentMark
    );

}
```

Then you can iterate the array quite easily:

```
foreach ($questions as $studentId => $studentData) {
    echo $studentData['studentAlias'].' - '.$studentData['studentforename'].' '.$studentData['studentsurname'].'<br/>';

    foreach ($studentData['questions'] as $questionId => $questionData) {
        echo '<strong>'.$questionData['questionno'].': '.$questionData['content'].'<br/>';
        echo $questionData['optiontype'].' - '.$questionData['noofanswers'].' - '.$questionData['answer'].' - '.$questionData['replytype'].' - '.$questionData['questionmarks'].'<br/>';
        echo $questionData['studentanswer'].' - '.$questionData['responsetime'].' - '.$questionData['mouseclick'].' - '.$questionData['studentmark'].'<br/>';
    }
}
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I will give it a test and see what the outcome is, +1 for attempting to answer question